# Creating shared pointer of object taking shared pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, object, shared-ptr

Trying to create a `std::shared_ptr` of an object which takes a `std::shared_ptr` as a parameter resulted in a "no matching constructor for initialization of 'object'" compile error.

My code looks as following:

```
// Sidebar Widgets
  _widgets.sideBarWidgetLeft = std::make_shared<SideBarWidget>();
  _widgets.sideBarWidgetLeft->hide();
  _widgets.sideBarWidgetRight = std::make_shared<SideBarWidget>();
  _widgets.sideBarWidgetRight->hide();

  // Pointer Test
  CalibrationManagementWidget* test = new CalibrationManagementWidget( _widgets.sideBarWidgetLeft, 0 );

  // Sidebar Left
  _widgets.calibrationManagementWidget = std::make_shared<CalibrationManagementWidget>( _widgets.sideBarWidgetLeft, 0 );
  _widgets.calibrationManagementWidget->hide();
  _widgets.cameraWidget = std::make_shared<CameraWidget>( 0, VISUALISATION_TYPE_NORMAL );
  _widgets.cameraWidget->hide();
```

While "Pointer Test" compiles just fine, the lines under "Sidebar Left" create named error. Is there something I'm doing wrong instantiating or isn't this possible in general?

Here is (one of) the error message(s):

```
/usr/include/c++/5.4.0/ext/new_allocator.h:120: Error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'CalibrationManagementWidget'
        { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
                             ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**EDIT:**

As requested I'll post some snippets which contain also the constructor of the CalibrationWidget.

calibrationwidget.h

```
...
Q_INVOKABLE CalibrationManagementWidget(QWidget* parent = 0 , VisualisationType visuType = VISUALISATION_TYPE_TRANSLATOR);
CalibrationManagementWidget( std::shared_ptr<SideBarWidget> sideBarWidget, QWidget* parent = 0 );
virtual ~CalibrationManagementWidget();
...
```

calibrationwidget.cpp

```
...
CalibrationManagementWidget::CalibrationManagementWidget(QWidget* parent, enum VisualisationType visuType) : CommonWindowWidget( WIDGET_TYPE_3D, "", "Calibration Management", 0, Ui::UI_WINDOW_FLAG_CLOSABLE, 0, parent, visuType) {
  _currentMessage = 0;
  _selectedCalibrationType = CALIBRATION_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
  _messageEventLoop = new QEventLoop(this);
  _updateTimer = new QTimer();
  setupUi();
}


CalibrationManagementWidget::CalibrationManagementWidget(std::shared_ptr<SideBarWidget> sideBarWidget, QWidget* parent) : CommonWindowWidget( WIDGET_TYPE_3D, "", "Calibration Management", 0, Ui::UI_WINDOW_FLAG_CLOSABLE, sideBarWidget, parent) {
  _currentMessage = 0;
  _selectedCalibrationType = CALIBRATION_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
  _messageEventLoop = new QEventLoop(this);
  _updateTimer = new QTimer();
  setupUi();
}

CalibrationManagementWidget::~CalibrationManagementWidget() {
  delete _messageEventLoop;
  _messageEventLoop = 0;
  delete _updateTimer;
  _updateTimer = 0;
}
...
```

Here are also snippets from the CommonWindowWidget.

commonwindowwidget.h

```
...
CommonWindowWidget(WidgetType widgetType, const QString& headerTitle = "Foldable Widget", const string& pageName = "Foldable Widget", unsigned int view = 0, unsigned int uiWindowFlags = 0, std::shared_ptr<SideBarWidget> sideBarWidget = 0, QWidget* parent = 0, VisualisationType visuType = VISUALISATION_TYPE_NORMAL);
    virtual ~CommonWindowWidget();
...
```

commonwindowwidget.cpp

```
...
CommonWindowWidget::CommonWindowWidget(WidgetType widgetType, const QString& headerTitle, const string& pageName, unsigned int view, unsigned int uiWindowFlags, std::shared_ptr<SideBarWidget> sideBarWidget, QWidget* parent, VisualisationType visuType) : CommonStackedWidget(widgetType, pageName, view, parent, visuType) {
  _windowFlags = uiWindowFlags;
  _sideBarWidget = std::move(sideBarWidget);

  setupUi();

  _ui.headerWidget->headerLabel()->setText( headerTitle );

  connect( _ui.headerWidget, SIGNAL(headerDoubleClicked()), this, SLOT(changeFoldState()));
  connect( _ui.headerWidget, SIGNAL(changeFoldStateClicked()), this, SLOT(changeFoldState()));
  connect( _ui.headerWidget, SIGNAL(closeClicked()), this, SLOT(navigateToHome()));
}

CommonWindowWidget::~CommonWindowWidget() {

}
...
```

Comment: Please show us the constructor of CalibrationManagementWidget (that one that should take shared pointer)

Comment: Since `CalibrationManagementWidget` is obviously a type of some kind, `something.CalibrationManagementWidget=whatever` makes as much sense as `something.int=whatever`. Whatever you're trying to do, it won't work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, it's `something.calibrationManagementWidget` (lowercase c), so that's likely a field named almost the same as the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When forwarded, 0 causes the parameter to be deduced as `int`, which is not convertible to a pointer anymore.

Only the *literal* 0 can represent a pointer, but after having been passed to `make_shared`, the literal becomes the `int` value 0, which causes the error, as the constructor expects a pointer.

Use `nullptr` instead:

```
_widgets.calibrationManagementWidget =
   std::make_shared<CalibrationManagementWidget>(
     _widgets.sideBarWidgetLeft, nullptr
   );
```

This is the main reason why `nullptr` was introduced.

Explanation: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-nullptr, about minute 28:00.

Comment: Thank you for that input! I know about this behavior, but it seems that it still works to use *p = 0, anyways I'm already replacing all those occurencies with "nullptr", there are just a looot of classes.

Comment: Of course, `*p = 0` works, since the compiler knows that 0 has to be treated as the 0 value of the pointer type. If you *forward* 0, however, the compiler has to *deduce* the type. The type will be deduced as being int, which is not the correct type for the constructor argument. Thus you get an error.